# Magento : Display html element based on product attribute set?

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7, if-statement

I wish to display a static block on the product page if the product belongs to a certain Attribute Set

For example if I was a fashion store, and I have an attribute set of "Footwear" I only want the static block to show on product pages when the attribute set matches "Footwear"

I have found a little bit of code that outputs the ID of the Attribute set but I want to turn it into an else if statement.

```
<?php

$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                ->setType('catalog_product')
                ->getTypeId();
$attributeSetName   = 'Footwear';
$attributeSetId     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
                    ->getFirstItem()
                    ->getAttributeSetId();
echo $attributeSetId;

?>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method to the `Product View Block`

(not to core file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php` of course):

```
public function checkAttributeSet($product = null, $attributeSetName = null)
{
    if(is_null($product) || is_null($attributeSetName)) 
        return false;

    $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
    $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());

    if($attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName() == $attributeSetName) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Then in `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`:

```
if($this->checkAttributeSet($_product, 'Monitors')):
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('monitor')->toHtml();
elseif($this->checkAttributeSet($_product, 'Footwear')):
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footwear')->toHtml();
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

FOR THE ADMINS WHO DELETE USEFUL INFORMATION FOR POINTS ON STACKOVERFLOW >>>> 3rd time replying to this post with updated material ya know just incase someone stumbles on this thread.

This is the updated magento 2.3 way of completing this task.

Add code to

> module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view

```html
        <?php    
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $attributeSet  = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');

        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());        
        $attributeSetRepository   = $attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
        $attribute_set_name       = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
        
        //$attribute_set_name_arr[] = $attribute_set_name; 
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($attribute_set_name);

        if( !empty($attribute_set_name) && $attribute_set_name == 'Rc' ) {
        // echo $this->getLayout()
      ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
      ->setBlockId('rcitems')
      ->toHtml();
        }     
        ?>
```

```
 setBlockId = The Identifier of the block in admin.
 Rc = is the attribute set
 no need to add to default.xml
```